# Webhook url on Fulfilment Page keeps disappearing

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I add the URL in the Webhook field of the Fulfilment page and it works. Start testing and for no reason it stops working. Check and the URL is gone and I have to add it again. Yes I am Saving and Yes I go back and check. This has started happening over the last few days.

Very annoying.

Comment: Please file a bug via Dialogflow email support: https://dialogflow.com/support

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have stopped now. Something that just happens sometimes.